# difference between micro8 and pacoblaze3 and how to use micro8

Tags: architecture, controller, processor, picoblaze

I am implementing a hardware project(Verilgo) in FPGA using pacoblaze3. Everything works fine, and then I heard that Micro8 could offer a faster speed. I want to switch the soft processor to Micro8. I found Micro8 has the exact interface as pacoblaze3 so I just change the pacoblaze3 module into a Micro8 module
before:

```
pacoblaze3 led_8seg_kcpsm
(
                  .address(address),
               .instruction(instruction),
                   .port_id(port_id),
              .write_strobe(write_strobe),
                  .out_port(out_port),
               .read_strobe(read_strobe),
                   .in_port(in_port),
                 .interrupt(interrupt),
             .interrupt_ack(interrupt_ack),
                     .reset(kcpsm3_reset),
                       .clk(clk));
```

after

```
micro8 led_8seg_kcpsm
    (
                      .address(address),
                   .instruction(instruction),
                       .port_id(port_id),
                  .write_strobe(write_strobe),
                      .out_port(out_port),
                   .read_strobe(read_strobe),
                       .in_port(in_port),
                     .interrupt(interrupt),
                 .interrupt_ack(interrupt_ack),
                         .reset(kcpsm3_reset),
                           .clk(clk));
```

I am pretty sure my source file for Micro8 is correct. I got it from MIT handout. Is there anything I need to change when I switch from PacoBlaze3 to Micro8?

Comment: Why don't you use the newest PicoBlaze from Xilinx with version 6 instruction set or the compatible [pauloBlaze](https://github.com/krabo0om/pauloBlaze)?

Comment: Um...it is a course project and using Micro8 is a bonus